# Computer restarts every time I suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend

This issue just started today. I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Precision laptop (dual booting with Windows 10) for a several weeks now with absolutely no problems. This morning, I closed my laptop lid for a few minutes, and when I opened it again, it restarted instead of just waking up. Now it does it every time I suspend, whether I close the lid or click the suspend button.

I haven't installed any new apps, made any changes to configurations, or updated in the past couple of weeks (although after I discovered the problem, I did update just to see if that would fix it). I'm finding plenty of people who are having problems with suspending, but not the same problem I'm having. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have this problem on a HP Z420 workstation. I have searched a good deal and could not yet find a cause.